# How does a regulairation parameter (lemda) help penalize the parameters theta0, theta1.....theta n?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I was going through the concept of regularisation and the use of regularisation parameter (lemda) to penalize theta0, theta1 ...theta n in a cost function
The concept says that we add `summation[from j=1 to n] of theta(j)^2` to cost function.

The component `summation[from j=1 to n] of theta(j)^2` will penalize or reduce theta1, theta2 etc to approx equal to 0

But my question is if `lemda = 10 and theta1 = 2, theta2 = 10` etc then 
`2^2+10^2 = 104`
`104*10(lemda) = 1040`
then how can adding this value of 1040 to cost function penalize the cost function.

Now consider `theta1 = 0.01 and theta2 = 0.02 and lemda = 100`
`0.01^2+0.02^2 = 0.0003` which is approximately equal to 0
now multiplying it with lemda -> `0.0003 * 100 = 0.03` will reduce the penalty

Hence, my doubt still holds there that whether I take bigger values of theta or smaller values of theta - How is cost function getting penalised?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, which language? If not, I'd guess that somewhere else (such as the [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) site) might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The cost function itself does not get penalized. It penalizes big values of `theta(i)` for all `i`. Why? The goal is to minimize the cost function, and it means to make it as close to 0 as possible(because it is non-negative). By adding the sum of `theta(i)^2` to the cost for all `i` we increase the cost function in case `theta(i)` is big. So for large `theta(i)` the cost automatically becomes bigger. That's why minimizing the cost functions implies that `theta(i)` will not be too big for all `i`.